# Realm Swift: retrieve user, object not returned when launching app

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I use Realm to store user information. When I launch the app, I look into the Realm database to see if there is a user object (to determine if the user is logged in or logged out).
Here's my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let config=Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 2,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion<1) || (oldSchemaVersion<2){
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: User.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                }
            }
    })

    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration=config

    do{
        let r=try Realm()
        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!.path)
        let u=r.objects(User.self)
        //prints 0
        print("user:", u.count)
    }catch let e as NSError{
        print("failed to initate realm /", e)
    }

    return true
}
```

I can see from Realm Browser that **the user is in the database**. But I can't get it. I'm probably initiating Realm the wrong way but I can't figure it out. Any idea?

---

**UPDATE**:
Here's the code I call to save the user when registering or logging:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    do{
        let r=try Realm()
        try r.write{
            let u=User(id:"id", username:"username")
                r.add(u)
             }
         }catch let e as NSError{
             print(e)
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: What prints in the console?

Comment: It prints "user: 0"

Comment: Can you share the code where you are saving the `User` object?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Your Realm code all looks correct.  Can you try querying the Realm somewhere else outside of the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore that the value was actually in the database. I close Realm browser, relaunched, and now the database is empty (I use the same printed path from my code to get it).

Comment: So sometimes the app launches, I get the user so I log him in. Sometimes, the database is empty so I can't log the user. I don't see anywhere else I delete the user object except when he chooses to logout.

Comment: (to answer your question, I tried somewhere else than in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but I could see the database was empty now (once I relaunched Realm Browser)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142658/discussion-between-dmorrow-and-marie-dm).

Comment: @MarieDm Could you provide us the reproducible project? If you cannot make public your code, please send it to `help@realm.io`.

Comment: I found out that I was deleting the Documents folder somewhere in the app (trying to delete a file with an empty path deleted the folder), so I also deleting the realm ddb... That's one problem solved! I still have to figure out why the user is sometimes logged out. It might come from the same kind of problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to the user is sometimes logged out issue? I have very similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: @claramelon sorry it was too long ago, I don't remember.